# Como salvar corretamente uma URL de imagem no banco MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, json, url, request

Estou testando o direcionamento de imagens com a URL. Porém durante os testes, a URL foi retornada com alterações como pode ser visto abaixo:

URL inserida no banco:

```
http://www.meusite.com.br/pastaimagem/logos/imageLogo.jpg
```

URL retornada pelo banco:

```
http:\/\/www.meusite.com.br\/pastaimagem\/logos\/imageLogo.jpg
```

Notei este problema enquanto testava a query pelo navegador.

Versão do PHP:

PHP: 5.4.37

Query usada para inserir a URL:

```
UPDATE  `meusite_sitebd`.`jump` SET  `urlimagem` =  'http://www.meusite.com.br/pastaimagem/logos/imageLogo.jpg' WHERE `register`.`idRegistro` =1;
```

Código em PHP usado para realizar a requisição:

```
<?php

include 'conexao.php';

//Converte para UTF8 os resultados da query
mysql_set_charset('UTF8');

// Retorna registro por id

$id = $_GET['idRegistro'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM registros WHERE idRegistro = '$id'";

$resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Erro: ".mysql_error());

// Crinha variável linha do tipo array
$linha = array();

  while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado))
    { 
        $linha [] = $r;
    }


 echo json_encode($linha);


mysql_close(); 

?>
```

Como podem ver é um código bem simples.

Comment: Não. Estou salvando somente a URL dela. Na verdade eu ja editei a pergunta. Ficou meio confusa, mas agora está mais legível. A imagem está em um diretório no próprio servidor.

Comment: Ok, como você está salvando a URL?

Comment: Na propria tela do PHPMyAdmin, eu faço a edição do registro e copio e colo a URL. Mas na tela do PHP a URL está normal. So aparece com as contra-barras quando recebo elas pela requisição.

Comment: O magic quotes está habilitado? Qual a versão do php? Poderia colocar o código do insert

Comment: Editei a questão e adicionei o código usado para atualizar o registro e inserir a URL e a versão do PHP. Vou verificar o magic quotes...

Comment: Por acaso seu código não tem um `addslashes` colocando essas barras?

Comment: Não. É a primeira vez que me deparo com este problema. :/

Comment: Vou adicionar o código que estou usando para a query...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por padrão [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) coloca barras para escapar alguns caracteres, para evitar esse comportamento, passe `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` no segundo argumento da função dessa forma as barras de escape não serão adicionadas.

```
echo json_encode($url,  JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

[Exemplo - ideone](http://ideone.com/to6uwr)

Baseado em: [How to remove backslash on json_encode() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7282755/1342547)

Comment: Perfeito! Funcionou!

Answer (score 3):

@Tiago Amaral vi que você setou seu banco para charset "UTF8" no php mais seu banco foi criado com esta mesma charset? no php sua charset tbm é "UTF8"? senão é ai que pode está o problema, verifique isso.
coloque isso no php para setar a charset do mesmo.

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8", true);
```

no arquivo de conexão com o banco coloque isso pra ver se resolve.

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
```

Comment: Sim o campo no banco esta como UT8. E no PHP tbm... No caso seria uma certa redundancia. Vou remover a conversao no php para testar.